# What is the difference between net profit and net banking income

Tags: banking, financial-literacy

For Societe Generale Analysts had expected net profit of €811.5m on net banking income of €6.47bn.

Why are they so different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find it helpful to read Wikipedia's article on an [Income Statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_statement). You asked about analysts' expectations, but I'll answer based on the actual income statement, since that's more relevant to the underlying question.

**Essentially, their reported "net banking income" does not have operating expenses or taxes taken out of it yet** (or various adjustments that they perform), whereas "net profit" does.

For Q1 2018, Société Générale reported Net banking income of €6.29 Billion. They had operating expenses of €4.73 Billion, leaving Gross operating income of €1.56 billion. They have various adjustments they make (-€208+1+16 million), and have to pay taxes of €370, leaving a total net income of €1.00 Billion (€154 million of which is attributable to non-controlling interests).